# Configuring middleware - Node Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middle ware function customerExists that should run before all processPayments requests. So I configured the route as follows. But the middleware function runs all the time when I run the server. How should I reconfigure the following codes

```
'use strict';

var payments = require('../controllers/payments.server.controller');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(payments.customerExists); // Middleware - 
  app.route('/api/process/payment/')
    .get(payments.processPayments);
};
```

Comment: `app.route('/api/process/payment/' payments.customerExists)
    .get(payments.processPayments);` have u tried this?

Comment: I tried this but not workout

Comment: `app.get('/api/process/payment/' payments.customerExists, payments.processPayments);` try this but both are same. it should work.

Comment: This worked out. I also found a soln that I edited above in question. Pls add this as answer. Thanks very much buddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`app.use(payments.customerExists)` will run by-default when app starts

If you not have more `/api/process/payment/` routes then above solution is perfect for you
Do while get request

```
'use strict';

var payments = require('../controllers/payments.server.controller');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/api/process/payment/', payments.customerExists, 
    payments.processPayments); 
};
```